# Fetch field from related model in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have `ResultTest` model with the following relation:

```
public function doctor()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Doctor', 'user_id', 'doctor_id');
}
```

Model `App\Doctor` has also relation:

```
public function distributor() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(DistributorContacts::class);
}
```

So, when I fetch data from model  `ResultTest`:

It is becomes complicated and ugly fetch specific field from related model:

```
dd($conclusion['test']->doctor()->first()->distributor->first()->name);
```

And sometimes there is not relation `->doctor()->first()` and it fails

Comment: here you are sharing with us doctor, distributor, and ResultTest models?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Question is how to handle error if not exist relation and how to make this more beauty

Comment: If a `Doctor` does not always have a `Distributor`, then you simply need to check for one before trying to access its properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `with` keyword

```
ResultTest::with('doctor')->first();
```

Rather than

```
dd($conclusion['test']->doctor()->first()->distributor->first()->name);
```

Comment: Downvoting, this is incorrect.  Using `with()` will [eager-load the results](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), so that a 2nd database call is not required to get that related data.  If you *don't* eager-load, you can still retrieve the data by calling the relationship (which executes another DB call).  Eager loading is about efficiency - it does not change whether or not the data can be retrieved or if it exists. The only difference between this code and OPs is that this uses 1 less DB call.

Comment: Anyway if not exist related data it invokes an error: `$conclusion['test']->doctor()->first()`

Comment: And why it return array instead one row? Cause it is relations hasOne